# Better way to run selenium webdriver tests?

Tags: xml, batch-file, ant, webdriver, testng

We run a large amount of tests with java webdriver every day. We use TestNG, and we use bat files to execute the TestNG XMLs, using the classed compiled by Eclipse. I'm wondering, though, if there's a better way to do this. Since we run hundreds (thousands?) of test cases daily, we have to resort creating testng XMLs that execute entire packages, otherwise we'd have to manually create an xml for each test, and that's not practical.

One problem with executing such large tests containing hundreds of classes is that if there's one major issue (such as webdriver stalling or hanging), the entire test will not run. Also, we have a listener that uploads to a server at the end of the test, so we have to wait hours for all results to be uploaded at once (something more in "real time" would be better). Another problem is if the VMs reboot for whatever reason, all "progress" is lost and we'd have to run the tests from the beginning.

I've seen Ant builds mentioned around the testng website, but I'm not sure what the advantages of ant would be over just using the bat files to execute the XMLs. Can anyone shed light on this? Or offer any solutions for executing a large number of tests with something more elegant than bat files?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you compile your classes?

Comment: I added a comment about it to my original post. We just use the classed that are automatically compiled by Eclipse.

Comment: How do you move the classes/data etc to the VM? manually?

Comment: Everything is stored on a network drive, so the VMs have direct access to everything they need.

Comment: So, you are not using `version control` - svn/git?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Eclipse for build (or Ant) I'd recommend to use Gradle (http://gradle.org/). It has great support for TestNG and you can run your test just using command like `gradlew clean test` (instead of bat files)

Instead of creating XML manually etc. you can use Test Groups in `@Test` annotation so you can pick tests based on groups not only on packages. Also you can pass group names via gradle - something like `gradlew clean build -PtestGroup=smoke,unit` (then pass it to TestNG in `build.gradle` file http://gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html)

For more "real time" result you can upload your results after each test/configuration method using `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter` (depends on your result processing structure)

If you want way more faster execution of Selenium tests there is basically one option (if you already optimized DOM processing etc.) and it's parallelism - 2 or more VMs and split tests based on groups/packages etc. or with some more sophisticated/programmatic method.